# concerned about security of data-* attributes?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, custom-data-attribute

i just started using data-* attributes to store custom attributes and values needed to View.  for example .

```
<div id='someId' data-ItemValues='SomeValues'>
</div>
```

based on the `data-*` i am doing some operations (CRUD) . what if user changed data-* attributes value in client side (ie from browser using firebug and some other developer tools)  ? 
i just want to know, is there any standards we need to follow or  want to know how community handle this scenario.

**Update :**

i will validate in serverside also. but in some scenario. data is not stored in server. it will be in mark up. it will save only when user will hit save button.

i will pick the data, from javacript and use ajax to send values to the server. but my concern is that if user changed the values in data-* attribute, such that even server side validation will meet the rule to pass. then how do i prevent them ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is the same it has always been.

[Never trust the client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). Always verify and validate the values are what you expect, on the server side.

This applies to values in hidden fields, data passed in through AJAX or anything that comes from a machine not in your control.

Comment: i will validate in serverside also. but in some scenario. data is not stored in server. it will be in mark up. it will save only when user will hit save button

Comment: @Ravi - This is no different from input the user enters into a form. You need to understand that anything rendered on a page can be tampered with.

Comment: ok. but can you suggest me a way how we can save such data. where we need to save all the data, when they hit save. without doing postback or accessing server.

Comment: @Ravi - How? You can pick it up in Javascript and either populate hidden form elements for posting or use AJAX.

Comment: i will pick the data, from javacript and use ajax to send values to the server. but my concern is that if user changed the values in data-* attribute, such that even server side validation will pass. then how do i prevent them ?

Comment: @Ravi - You would need to check against the data you have put into the page. I have to assume that if you put it on the page, you can get it again for checking.

Comment: If nothing else, you can always sign the data sent to the client. Then the server-side validation will just be verifying the signature.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that you store in markup or javascript objects can be easily tampered with, so my suggestion would be to perform server-side validation of anything that comes from such attributes/objects, especially if you use it for CRUD or any similar operations!

Answer (score 1):

**Never Depend on (Trust) on Client Side data.**

Always do Server side validations to make sure the transaction is happeneing to the correct data. Client side should be to make the app more interactive and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the data stored in data-* attributes should be treated just like any other client data, i.e. you should distrust the data and validate it properly on the server.